# After upgrading Android WebView on Android TV, hls 264 videos are not being played anymore

Tags: webview, ionic4, android-tv

After upgrading Android WebView to 80.0.3987.99 version, Android TV is not playing live HLS videos anymore (h264) on WebView based app (ionic 4).

Operating system: Android TV 9 (Exclusively on Android TV)
Kernel version: 4.9.113

**Steps to reproduce:**

(1) Just try to open a HLS h264 live video (m3u8 manifest) on a WebView based app on Android TV device using WebView 80.0.3987.99. You can use the attached APK.

Expected result: Video is not being played.

**Downgrading WebView to minor versions (for example, 75.0.03770.143) and restarting the application, video is actually played with no issues.**

APK download for testing:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/attachment?aid=433346&signed_aid=j3jgAQISOSoCW4DBQcRFXw==

---

**Logs in logcat:**

```
2020-02-12 15:57:40.206 24233-24336/com.eninetworks.enitvtester I/cr_MediaCodecBridge: create MediaCodec video decoder, mime video/avc

2020-02-12 15:57:40.277 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained

2020-02-12 15:57:40.373 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester I/MediaCodec: MediaCodec will operate in async mode
2020-02-12 15:57:40.382 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xd1a7f008, reason connectToSurface

2020-02-12 15:57:40.383 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester I/MediaCodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] setting surface generation to 24814593

2020-02-12 15:57:40.383 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xd1a7f008, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)

2020-02-12 15:57:40.383 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xd1a7f008, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)

2020-02-12 15:57:40.386 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester I/AmAVUtils: AmAVUtils::getComponentRole isEncoder :0 mime:video/avc 

2020-02-12 15:57:40.386 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester V/AVUtils: AVUtils::getComponentRole

2020-02-12 15:57:40.393 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -2147483648

2020-02-12 15:57:40.403 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester I/AmAVUtils: AmAVUtils::isAudioExtendFormat input = video/avc


2020-02-12 15:57:40.470 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xd1a7f008, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage

2020-02-12 15:57:40.470 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xd1a7f008, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage

2020-02-12 15:57:40.470 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0xd1a7f008 for 1920x1080, color 0x11, rotation 0, usage 0x402b00

2020-02-12 15:57:40.471 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] setting nBufferCountActual to 10 failed: -1010

2020-02-12 15:57:40.472 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] setting nBufferCountActual to 9 failed: -1010

2020-02-12 15:57:40.473 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] setting nBufferCountActual to 8 failed: -1010

2020-02-12 15:57:40.475 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] setting nBufferCountActual to 7 failed: -1010

2020-02-12 15:57:40.475 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/ACodec: Failed to allocate buffers after transitioning to IDLE state (error 0xfffffc0e)

2020-02-12 15:57:40.475 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -1010)

2020-02-12 15:57:40.478 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xfffffc0e, actionCode 0, while in state 5

2020-02-12 15:57:40.478 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/libc: Access denied finding property "media.metrics.enabled"

2020-02-12 15:57:40.492 24233-24349/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/AHierarchicalStateMachine: Warning message AMessage(what = 'omxI') = {
      int32_t type = 0
      int32_t event = 0
      int32_t data1 = 0
      int32_t data2 = 1
    } unhandled in root state.

2020-02-12 15:57:40.506 24233-24348/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xd1a7f008, reason disconnectFromSurface

**2020-02-12 15:57:40.518 24233-24336/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/cr_MediaCodecBridge: Cannot start the media codec**

android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: start failed
at android.media.MediaCodec.native_start(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaCodec.start(MediaCodec.java:2068)
at org.chromium.media.MediaCodecBridge.c(PG:8)
at org.chromium.media.MediaCodecBridgeBuilder.createVideoDecoder(PG:68)

2020-02-12 15:57:40.521 24233-24336/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/cr_MediaCodecBridge: Releasing: OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome

2020-02-12 15:57:40.528 24233-24336/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/cr_MediaCodecBridge: Codec released

2020-02-12 15:57:40.545 24233-24282/com.eninetworks.enitvtester D/AudioTrack: stop() called with 16940 frames delivered

2020-02-12 15:57:45.549 24233-24282/com.eninetworks.enitvtester E/libc: Access denied finding property "media.metrics.enabled"

2020-02-12 15:57:45.544 24233-24233/com.eninetworks.enitvtester W/AudioThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:48242): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:media_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=2183 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c47,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:media_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Comment: You are not the only one with this issue. I'm also facing it. Even Facebook TV app is not playing videos with this webview :/. I would be happy to see a solution

Answer (score 0):

So, i've made little bit of progress. h.264 have issues with latest webview on Android TV. It even had on previous one. I've played with ffmpeg and apparently h.265 main 4.1 coded mp4 is not causing this issue. For me it still leaves with three.js texture issue with new codec. Try converting video, maybe it will bring luck to you and works :)

Answer (score 0):

For those having this behaviour, there is a bug in the WebKit 80 which is accepted and it is being fixed on the release planned for march 17h.

I reported the bug to Chromium team, here you can read more about it:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1051705